# Unable to fetch value from mailosaur using protractor, although same is working with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, protractor, angular-promise

I'm trying to integrate Protractor code with mailosaur to handle the email functionality but unable to fetch the value while coding in Protractor. When I'm trying the same code in node.js it is working correctly and I'm able to get the value. Below are the code:

In Node.js file:

```
var Mailosaur = require("mailosaur")("Your_API_Key");
var mailbox = new Mailosaur.Mailbox("MailboxID");
console.log("Here it begins!");
mailbox.getEmails(function(err, emails) {
console.log(err);
console.log(emails);
console.log("Are you even going inside?");});
```

Run it in cmd: **node filename.js**

Result: Displaying the data in Json format in cmd.

Same thing with Protractor code is not working, below is the code.

```
describe('Test Mail', function() {
it('should display the data', function(){
    var Mailosaur = require("mailosaur")("Your_API_Key");
    var mailbox = new Mailosaur.Mailbox("MailboxID");

    console.log("Here it begins!");
    mailbox.getEmails(function(err, emails) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(emails);
    console.log("Are you even going inside?");});})});
```

Run it using a config file mentioning the respective spec file: **protractor config.js**

Result: Only the top log appears i.e. "Here it begins!", not displaying the content of the mail as in the case above with node.js.

Kindly suggest in case I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Trick here that you are not actually schedule some actions to protractor control flow, so jasmine thinks that test is finished.

Check this - 
http://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow

> Protractor adapts Jasmine so that each spec automatically waits until
>   the control flow is empty before exiting.

For your code something like this might help - just put promise to control flow:

```
describe('Test Mail', function() {
    it('should display the data', function(){
        var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
        var Mailosaur = require("mailosaur")("Your_API_Key");
        var mailbox = new Mailosaur.Mailbox("MailboxID");

        console.log("Here it begins!");
        mailbox.getEmails(function(err, emails) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(emails);
            console.log("Are you even going inside?");
            deferred.resolve();
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but it is not working in this way. Although when I tried after adding a sleep after the callback function finished it got the expected result for me. But I was looking for better approach to handle it rather using sleep.